# Should I get EE or CS major?

Tags: electromagnetism, computers

I don't know whether this is the place to ask this. I'm sorry if this is the wrong place. I'm a first year university student in Electrical Engineering and Informatics School. In my second year, I have to choose my major. From 6 choices, I ended up in either CS or EE. I've been loving CS from my mid school. However I'm afraid that CS is not a really good choice since there are tons of CS graduate and I couldn't keep up with my junior, and got sacked from my job. I'm thinking of taking EE major because it's one of the most general major and I still could get CS for my master degree later. Another reason I'm considering EE is because of it pays better than CS. Which major should i take? Should I prioritize wages, or what I really like? I'm a very tolerant person. I could like what I don't really like after some time. I also don't mind on studying hard subjects because I love to explore new things. Both of these majors have A ABET Accreditation.

I love things that related to:
 - Artificial Intelligent
 - Cryptograpgy
 - Hacking
 - Modern Physics
 - Theoritical Mathematics ( Mathematical paradoxes, Series, etc.)
 - Theoritical Physics (Schrodinger, Maxwell, Relativity, Time dillatation)
 - Paradoxes
 - Discrete Mathematics
 - Programming
 - Computer-related things
 - Electromagnetical Waves

I'm interested in:

- Biomedical
- Neuroscience(bionic)
- Semiconductors
- Creating something (GPS wristband, Internet of Things)

I can do things that relates to:
 - Calculus etc.(I do love this actually)
 - Classic Physics
 - Electrical Circuits(but I don't really like to)

Thank you for answering.

Comment: I'd do both, you can also do undergrad in one, and grad in the other. However, questions that are opinion-based aren't appropriate for this forum. See [What topics can I ask about here?](http://electronics.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: Again, I apologize if this is not the place. The thread may be closed if this post violates the forum. But thank you for replying. I have to pick one though. Or I could get EE as my major and several CS classes. This has been bugging me for months and now I couldn't even sleep just because of this.

Comment: Split the difference and get a degree in Computer Engineering.  You get a little hardware and a little software and a whole lot of chaos.

Comment: The job market for programmers is very strong, and has been for a long time. Regardless of many very good programmers already working, demand is high and there seem always to be open positions. Yes, EEs may make more money, but there are fewer of them, so the competition for the available jobs may be more intense. Since your passion is for CS, I would say to follow your heart. I also think you're fortunate to have a relatively easy decision in this respect. Good luck.

Comment: @CHendrix I've been thinking to take CpE, but sadly my university doesn't have one

Comment: @OleksandrR. Is it possible for CS graduate to make more money than EE graduate by the time flows? And thank you for your answer. I will consider this

Comment: Thank you for the answer. It's ok to close the thread now. I will highly consider of taking CS major.

Comment: EE has changed a lot from the old days.  The days of wiring a bunch of chips and calling it a day is no longer practical. Today's microcontrollers are incredibly powerful and dirt cheap and replace huge chunks of specialized logic chips. Consequently, you have to know a lot more programming.

Answer (score 2):

Most of the things you list that you like/love are very CS &/or math oriented, not EE-oriented, and then you top it off with "Electrical Circuits (but I don't really like to)", which pretty much clinches it - if you don't like "making things", then that's not a good sign for happiness.

As for whether you should do something you're good at vs. what you love doing, a common mantra in the last decade or two has been "Do what you love, and the money will come", but I think that's been shown to not necessarily be true; or at least "Do what you're good at, and you'll learn to love it, and the money will also come."

Lastly, the choices you make here early in life are not unchangeable, you aren't locked in.  OK, so if you make a choice and decide after 2 or 4 or 6 years you don't like it, so you go back to school and learn something new.  So what?  That's life!  Few people know exactly what they want to do for the rest of their lives when they're young AND actually end up doing it that long.

Answer (score 0):

There is a lot of crossover between the two fields. The question is, is what sub field do you want to end up in? What do you want to do when you go into work? Do you want to sit in front of a computer from 9 to 5? Or do you want to mess around with stuff?

The biggest question to answer is: What is going to keep it interesting and keep you motivated. Does coding do that for you? If it does then stick with the CS degree learn java and all of that other (I'll call it nonsense). Get a developer job at a software company.

Do you like coding at a lower level in C or assembly and working with microprocessors? go for a computer engineering degree.

Are you more hands on? some jobs let you play with stuff. Like Some Analog Engineers, Hardware Engineers, Mechatronic Engineers.

They have signal processing jobs where you are analyzing noise and building error correction coding systems, which is really math intensive.
Control engineers can be more hands on but also math intensive.

There are quantitative analysis people that do nothing but math and build mathematical models to analyze data. Electrical Engineers also take similar maths.
I could go on for a while, I hope this gets you thinking about what you want to do. You need to find out what motivates you. If its cash then go on indeed and find the jobs with the best salary and shoot for one of those. If what motivates you is doing interesting work, then make that your top priority.

Prioritize what you think will motivate you first. Then find out how to get that out of a job. Pick a job that you think will fill your interests and keep you motivated. If you like what you do, and love coming into work everyday then your career will be great.

Search on indeed.com for different jobs that you might think you would like. Read into the job descriptions, they give you a good hint on what you would be doing from day to day. Get a top 3 list and start gravitating towards those in school. If there is stuff in school that you like doing then look for jobs where you could do more of that. Keep in mind that work is work. It sucks, you also need to have a good work ethic to keep you going through the rough times.

Another tip is do you want to specialize in one area and get really good at it? or do you want to do a lot of different things? The classes that you need to take will need to reflect this desire. If you find one area that you like then specialize. If your unsure than keep it broad. Take a little bit in each area or take a lot in one area, but have a few "sub areas". Balance this out with how much time and money you want to spend on an education.

When I was in high school I knew I wanted to be an engineer. I decided to go into electrical engineering because it was the most difficult, and I wanted a challenge. I took a very broad class base, I knew I didn't want to get sucked into one area, so I took as many classes in different areas. I wanted to become a systems engineer, I settled for an analog engineer at a small company where I get to do a lot of different things.